# android emulator over logged

Tags: android, android-emulator, logcat, android-logcat

I'm developing an android application using eclipse (ADT).
I've been doing it for a few months now, but suddenly today, when I start the emulator, it's over logging the logcat with this message:

```
Level: D
Application: system_process
Tag: ThrottleService
Text: deleteing /data/system/throttle/407640534
```

I searched and could not find a single thing regarding anything similar to this problem, it is impossible to use the logging system like this since it prints the same message more than 10 times per second.
I can of course use filters, but sometimes you want to watch all of the logs.

Any idea what this message is about and why it's being logged so often?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: have you installed or upgraded any of your apps? just googling "android ThrottleService" comes up with a bunch of results, I think it's an internal app.

Comment: no, i haven't installed or updated anything, it's an emulator, other than the application that i'm developing there's nothing on it that i added.

the message is being logged as the emulator starts working, before i run my application.

i did find a lot of results for "android ThrottleService" but not for the logging messages.

Comment: you could try a hard reset of the emulator? see if that works. [there's instructions here](https://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/2326153647349c14).

Comment: @MattK Please enter your comment as an answer so that it can be accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a hard reset of the emulator. [Instructions are here](https://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/2326153647349c14).